# net use /d windows 7

Tags: windows, cmd, system-administration

I'm on Windows 7 and having a bit of trouble with a command. Obviously this is for a homework assignment, I just want someone to sort of lead me in the right direction. In command prompt I am to run the command

```
net use * /d
```

I have tried this and it results in "there are no entries in the list." I have searched online trying to find what this command would do and I can not find the answer, I can't find it in the textbook for the class either so this really has me stumped. I kind of have a grasp for what net use is used for, I just can't seem to find out what said command would do. Also, I get the same result when I run just "net use"

Comment: Teach a man to fish: `net help use`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is used to delete a network mapped drive. So you will have to create one first.

```
net use x: "\\remote-computer\shared-folder"
```

This will map `shared-folder`, which is a shared folder on a remote computer (not the computer on which you are working) named `remote-computer` to `x:` drive. This means that when you access `x:` on your computer you will see the contents of `\\remote-computer\shared-folder`.

If you want the operating system to automatically assign a drive letter, you can use the following command.

```
net use * "\\remote-computer\shared-folder"
```

Now that you have created such mappings. You can delete them in the following way.

```
net use x: /d
```

This will delete the `x:` drive mapping that we created above.
To delete all existing mappings, use `*`.

```
net use * /d
```

Instead of remote computer you can try this on a single computer as well. Use 127.0.0.1 (or your computer's name) for computer name.

Example session using local computer only:

[image: net use command usage]

Note that in the 4th command in the picture, I get the same error that you were getting, "there are no entries in the list", since in the 3rd command in the picture you can see that I delete all mappings.